# How can I find all the folders that contain certain file extensions in Bash?

Tags: bash

I need to write a Bash script (preferably a one-liner) to find all the **subdirectories** under the current directory which contain any files with a certain file extension, namely `.tf`. The tricky part is that there may be more than one `.tf` file in a folder, and *I need the folders* - **not** the filenames.

So for example, suppose my directory contents look something like this:

```
.
├── docs
│   ├── README.md
│   └── diagram.png
├── project
│   └── main.py
├── Makefile
├── terraform
│   ├── environments
│   │   ├── prod
│   │   │   └── main.tf
│   │   └── staging
│   │       └── main.tf
│   └── module
│       ├── ecs.tf
│       ├── rds.tf
│       ├── s3.tf
│       ├── security_group.tf
│       ├── sqs.tf
│       └── variable.tf
├── tests
|   └── test_main.py
└── .terraform
    └── ignore_me.tf
```

In this case I would want the command to return `terraform/module`, `terraform/environments/prod`, and `terraform/environments/staging`. I also need a way to filter out certain directories that should never be included. In the example above note that I did not include the dot-file directory `.terraform`.

I already know how to write the following find command, which can find the `.tf` files themselves:

```
find . -name '*.tf' -not -path '*.terraform*'
```

However I'm not sure how to write a command to find the directories which contain those files.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use find's `-printf` action to print out just the directory name, and then remove duplicates:

```
find . -name '*.tf' -not -path '*.terraform*' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u
```

The `-printf '%h\n'` prints out the name of the directory containing matched files, while the `sort -u` at the end removes duplicates.

Comment: This will still produce incorrect output if you have directory names which contain newlines. These are obviously an uncommon corner case but it bears pointing out.

Comment: Also the printf option is not available on alpine

Comment: The question did not specify Alpine as a requirement.  If you want to use this solution on Alpine, first `apk install findutils`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
shopt -s globstar

echo **/*.tf | xargs dirname | sort -u
```

Comment: This doesn't work if any of the file or directory names contain spaces.

Comment: I agree. Your answer is more complete. I would suggest adding [[ -f "$i" ]] || continue in your loop for the cases where nothing is found and i is **/*.tf or there is a directory with .tf extension.

Answer (score 1):

This `find` command should also work:

```
find . -type d -not -path '*/.terraform*' \
-exec bash -c 'shopt -s failglob; ( : "$1"/*.tf ) 2>/dev/null && echo "$1"' - {} \;
```

- `failglob` returns failure if glob pattern fails.
- `find` command scans each directory in current path and `bash -c` checks for presence of `*.tf` files in each directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
shopt -s globstar  # to enable support for **

for i in **/*.tf; do echo "${i%/*}"; done | sort -u
```

If you don't have `**` enabled already, the `shopt` line will do it for you.

We iterate over all `*.tf` files in all subdirectories and print out their directory names (by chopping off all trailing `/*` components). `sort -u` is used to remove duplicates.